# In Ember what is the best way to stop click event propagation with select tag

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js

In Ember, I want to have a parent div that when clicked will call an action, except if a select tag is clicked within that div.  I eventually came up with a solution but it's not very good and was wondering if someone could explain why bubbles=false does not work in this case, and how I can get access to the event on the selectValue action (details below).

Originally I had:

```
<div class="parent-class" {{action 'shouldNotBeCalledOnSelect'}}>
    <select onchange={{action "selectValue" value="target.value"}}>
        <option class="default-option" disabled selected value>-</option>
        {{#each score.range as |valueChoice|}}
            <option value={{valueChoice}} selected={{eq score.value valueChoice}}>{{valueChoice}}</option>
        {{/each}}
    </select>
</div>
```

But I didn't want the action 'shouldNotBeCalledOnSelect' to be called when the select tag is clicked.  I tried bubbles=false on the selectValue action, but this didn't work.  I couldn't think of a way to pass the event with the selectValue action as it is, if I could then I could call

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

With an action you can get the event by using

```
onclick={{action 'someAction'}}
```

and then the event can be retrieved in the Javascript as the last parameter.  The solution I have achieved, which is a bit rubbish, is to have both onchange and onclick events on the select tag and use onclick exclusively for stopping propagation.

```
<div class="parent-class" {{action 'shouldNotBeCalledOnSelect'}}>
    <select onchange={{action "selectValue" value="target.value"}} onclick={{action 'stopPropagation'}}>
        <option class="default-option" disabled selected value>-</option>
        {{#each score.range as |valueChoice|}}
            <option value={{valueChoice}} selected={{eq score.value valueChoice}}>{{valueChoice}}</option>
        {{/each}}
    </select>
</div>
```

In the javascript I then have:

```
selectValue(value) {
    this.set('score.value', value);
    this.get('score').save();
},

stopPropagation(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
},

shouldNotBeCalledOnSelect() {
    console.log("CALLED");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to handle both `onclick` and `onchange`; because they are different events and the one that bubbles to div element is `onclick`. You cannot prevent the click event to propagate to div element by preventing `onchange` event from bubbling.

Secondly, the answer kumkanillam proivded will not work!!! See my [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/1d5f61b41e89be1d5d94733319ba4b3c?openFiles=components.my-component.js%2C) where I tried kumkanillam's proposed solution and the correct way to use `bubbles=false` for first and second selects respectively.

Here is the reason why `bubbles=false` does not work for the first select and works for the second select from Ember's official API. "To disable bubbling with closure style actions you must create your own wrapper helper that makes use of event.stopPropagation()". See the [documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_action) for details.

To sum up, if you use closure actions which is the case for your original posting you must write an action handler and call `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent bubbling of the event. If you use old style action helper (the second select in twiddle) then the `bubbles=false` will work.

You can read more about action helpers in the following [link](http://miguelcamba.com/blog/2016/01/24/ember-closure-actions-in-depth/) to learn more about action helpers.

Comment: Thanks for response and the explanation.  I have a lot to read up on.  My reputation is not high enough to upvote but when it is I will.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop event propagation through `bubbles=false` argument to action helper. but inside `onchange` action handler you can't stop `onclick` event bubbling. so in your use case, you can just define noop function and define `bubbles=false`. 
Your solution is the only way to go(AFAIK).

```
<div class="parent-class" {{action 'shouldNotBeCalledOnSelect'}}>
    <select onchange={{action "selectValue" value="target.value"}} {{action 'fnToStopPropagation' bubbles=false}}>
        <option class="default-option" disabled selected value>-</option>
        {{#each score.range as |valueChoice|}}
            <option value={{valueChoice}} selected={{eq score.value valueChoice}}>{{valueChoice}}</option>
        {{/each}}
    </select>
</div>
```

Define empty action handler,

```
fnToStopPropagation() {
}
```

Comment: your solution will not work; because `bubbles=false` will not work for closure actions. it only works for old style actions. you need to call `event.stopPropagation()` for closure actions. see my answer for details.

Comment: In my testing, I have actually done it without closure so it worked. but while answering I copied OP's code and got into the same trap(closure style actions can't stop event bubbling). thanks for pointing it out. updated my answer

Comment: sometimes that happens, no worries.